# Inverse of pow(a,b,c) decrypt

Tags: python, math

I am working on a python decryption code using an encryption code that is already available.

In the encryption code, I have `X = pow(a,b,c)`
I know X, a, c. How can I know value b?

Comment: What is `pow`???

Comment: Assuming that `a` is the base, `b` is the power, and `c` is the `mod c`-part, then this would be the discrete logarithm problem, which is practically intractable.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb It's a builtin function...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: The built-in function that I (and probably most people) know takes two input arguments - base and exponent.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb [It takes  up to three.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that

- `a` is the base,
- `b` is the power, and
- `c` is the `mod c`-part in `a^b mod c`,

then computing `b` given `a`, `c` and `a^b mod c` would be the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), which is practically intractable for the cases you'd be usually interested in when dealing with cryptographic algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, that's the point.  `pow(a,b,c)` is a ** b modulo c, where modulo means the remainder in an integer division by c. For example, `pow(4, 3, 5)` is 4 ** 3 modulo 5, which is 4 (4 ** 3 is 64, modulo 5 is 4 because that's the remainder of 60:5).

But you also get 4 as a result of, for example, `pow(4, 1, 5)` (because 4 ** 1 = 4, giving a remainder of 4).

So the bottom line is: You can't unambiguously derive b from having X, a and c in your equation because there are multiple bs that will fulfil the equation. That's one of the reasons why asymmetric encryption likes to use the modulo function.